# How to convert as pdf while dealing with xml nodes in mxGraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, mxgraph

I am implementing the graph editor using mxGraph javascript library and able to display the diagram and save the diagram.
Now,I have to export the diagram in to PDF file.

Primary question is,
Is there any other builtin feature is available on mxGraph library itself?
I used mxImageExport() class to exporting PNG image then its is redirecting to null url page.[redirect page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYaDn.png)

Here is the code:

```
function convertPDF() {
            var graph = universalGraph; // get xml form the graph stored in graph variable
            var xmlDoc = mxUtils.createXmlDocument();
            var root = xmlDoc.createElement('output');
            xmlDoc.appendChild(root);
            var xmlCanvas = new mxXmlCanvas2D(root);
            var imgExport = new mxImageExport();
            imgExport.drawState(graph.getView().getState(graph.model.root), xmlCanvas);
            var bounds = graph.getGraphBounds();
            var w = Math.ceil(bounds.x + bounds.width);
            var h = Math.ceil(bounds.y + bounds.height);
            var xml = mxUtils.getXml(root);
            new mxXmlRequest('export', 'format=png&w=' + w +
                    '&h=' + h + '&bg=#F9F7ED&xml=' + encodeURIComponent(xml))
                .simulate(document, '_self');
        }
```

(or) else I have to use regular JS PDF library?(*I cannot convert the HTML content inside  tag in to PDF, While converting it is showing
graph's background only no single shapes are in it. Since it is from XML nodes, I referred the internet and asked me to convert from XML in to SVG then PDF
but this method also not work because I have received the blank PDF file.*)

Here is the code:

```
function savePDF() {
    var imgData;
    html2canvas($(".svgClass"), {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                'image/png');
            console.log(imgData);
            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
            doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
            window.open(imgData);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Show your code so we can help you

Comment: I added the code and giving a detailed description about am facing the issue.